# How to find the index of the max/min element on a list?

Tags: python-3.x, matrix-indexing

I have a multidimentional list called `dist`. I want to get the position of the max element on this list/ matrix **without using NumPy**. How can I do it with built-in functions? I am using Python 3.6

```
dist = [[    0.0,  
          1804.04,
          2120.09,
          5502.24],
        [ 1804.04,
             0.0,
          7395.44,
          5828.17]]
```

Comment: Why without NumPy? It's so simple **and fast** using NumPy, you only have to use `np.argmax` and `np.unravel_index`.

Comment: @Michael thank you for both comment and editing. My assignment needs to be done by built-in functions.

Comment: I found the answer: 

for i in range(len(dist)):
    for j in range(len(dist)):
        if dist[i][j] == max(max(dist)):
            max_index = (i,j)

Answer (score 0):

Even though I strongly suggest NumPy (see comment below the question of OP), this one is without NumPy (only uses the built-in function [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/functions.html#enumerate) and also works for ragged arrays):

```
dist = [[    0.0,  
          1804.04,
          2120.09,
          5502.24],
        [ 1804.04,
             0.0,
          7395.44,
          5828.17]]  # list of lists

maximum, max_line, max_col = 0, 0, 0  # !!!
for line, l in enumerate(dist):
    for col, c in enumerate(l):
        if c > maximum: maximum, max_line, max_col = c, line, col
print(maximum, max_line, max_col)
```

In the line marked with `!!!` it is assumed that only positive values are in your matrix `dist` (which from the name `dist` and its symmetry in the unedited post of OP, as well as the zero-elements on the diagonal I assumed to be plausible). Otherwise one would have to choose a smaller starting value for `maximum`.

Here's how it would work with NumPy (see [`np.argmax`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.argmax.html) and [`np.unravel_index`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.unravel_index.html)):

```
import numpy as np
dist = np.array(dist)  # array
print(np.unravel_index(np.argmax(dist), dist.shape))
```